# Proxy detection in iOS

Tags: ios, proxy

I would like to find out programmatically if the user is using a proxy in iOS. Is there a way to detect it with the new api's (ios 7 or 8)?
Also, Is it possible to find out if the user has proxy unknowingly?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply find the proxy in the `CFDictionaryRef` response.

```
CFDictionaryRef dicRef = CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings();
```

if proxy is enable then you can parse it like this.

```
 const CFStringRef proxyCFstr = (const CFStringRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(dicRef,
                                                                           (const void*)kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPProxy);
```

based on this you can make detect if proxy is enabled or not.

Answer (score 1):

By default NSStream based sockets do not detect the System proxy settings, which is very inconvenient if you are trying to debug your NSStream based SSL traffic in Charles Proxy for example. To set the proxy setting for the streams I simply use:

```
NSInputStream  *inStream;
NSOutputStream *outStream;

//...assign the streams...

NSDictionary    *proxySettings = CFBridgingRelease(CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings());
[inStream  setProperty:proxySettings forKey:NSStreamSOCKSProxyConfigurationKey];
[outStream setProperty:proxySettings forKey:NSStreamSOCKSProxyConfigurationKey];
```